# Convert 3D Matrix decimal entity to 3D Binary entities

Tags: matlab

Basically i have a 3d matrix of rgb entities and i want to change it into an 8 bit 3d binary entities if any body can assist.

```
A(:,:,1) = [123 7 8; 1 98 4; 64 39 6];
A(:,:,2) = [1 0 4; 3 6 5; 9 8 80];
A(:,:,3) = [7 96 3; 4 5 67; 129 9 98];
```

**Into**

```
B(:,:,1) = [01111010 00000111 00001000; 00000001 01100010 00000100; 01000000 00100111 00000110];
B(:,:,2) = [00000001 00000000 00000100; 00000011 00000110 00000101; 00001001 00001000 01010000];
B(:,:,3) = [00000111 01100000 00000011; 00000100 00000101 01000011; 10000001 00001001 01100010];
```

Comment: Do you want them stored as a string or char? Otherwise, for example, `00000111` will be stored as `111`. Is this the intended result?

Comment: as a char actually because i want to keep the extra bits for future manipulation

Comment: btw there is a typo in the question. 123 should be converted to `01111011`; not `01111010`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dec2bin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) converts decimal to binary character vector. [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) is for converting them to cell array to make the required [reshaping](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) possible.

```
B = reshape(cellstr(dec2bin(A)), size(A));
```